# RHEL openshift enterprise 3.1 Installation error when Gathering information from hosts

Tags: openshift, openshift-3, openshift-enterprise

Here is the complete wizard output when installing Openshift Enterprise 3.1 with ansible 2.3 on RHEL 7.6 with Python 2.7.5

*** Installation Summary ***

Hosts:
- master.mine.kt.com
  - OpenShift Master
  - OpenShift Node (Unscheduled)
  - Etcd (Embedded)
  - Storage
- slave.mine.kt.com
  - OpenShift Node (Dedicated)

Total OpenShift Masters: 1
Total OpenShift Nodes: 2

NOTE: Add a total of 3 or more Masters to perform an HA installation.

Gathering information from hosts...
 [WARNING]: Failure using method (v2_runner_on_ok) in callback plugin (): runner_on_ok() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)
 [WARNING]: Failure using method (v2_runner_on_failed) in callback plugin (): runner_on_failed() takes at least 3 arguments (3 given)
There was a problem fetching the required information. Please see /tmp/ansible.log for details.

Upon checking /tmp/ansible.log I noticed below error not sure where the problem is.

2018-12-11 21:06:53,469 p=8325 u=root |  ok: [slave.mine.kt.com] => {"changed": false, "msg": "", "rc": 0, "results": ["yum-utils-1.1.31-50.el7.noarch providing yum-utils is already installed"]}
2018-12-11 21:06:54,610 p=8325 u=root |  ok: [master.mine.kt.com] => {"changed": false, "msg": "", "rc": 0, "results": ["yum-utils-1.1.31-50.el7.noarch providing yum-utils is already installed"]}
2018-12-11 21:06:54,628 p=8325 u=root |  TASK [openshift_facts : Gather Cluster facts and set is_containerized if needed] ************************************************************************************************************
2018-12-11 21:06:57,138 p=8325 u=root |  An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: TypeError: ansible_facts() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
2018-12-11 21:06:57,141 p=8325 u=root |  fatal: [master.mine.kt.com]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "module_stderr": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_yVIjg6/ansible_module_openshift_facts.py\", line 2101, in \n    main()\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_yVIjg6/ansible_module_openshift_facts.py\", line 2082, in main\n    protected_facts_to_overwrite)\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_yVIjg6/ansible_module_openshift_facts.py\", line 1574, in **init**\n    self.system_facts = ansible_facts(module)\nTypeError: ansible_facts() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)\n", "module_stdout": "", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE", "rc": 0}
2018-12-11 21:06:57,143 p=8325 u=root |   [WARNING]: Failure using method (v2_runner_on_failed) in callback plugin (): runner_on_failed() takes at least 3 arguments (3 given)

2018-12-11 21:06:57,439 p=8325 u=root |  fatal: [slave.mine.kt.com]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "module_stderr": "Shared connection to slave.mine.kt.com closed.\r\n", "module_stdout": "Traceback (most recent call last):\r\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_k7KJk0/ansible_module_openshift_facts.py\", line 2101, in \r\n    main()\r\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_k7KJk0/ansible_module_openshift_facts.py\", line 2082, in main\r\n    protected_facts_to_overwrite)\r\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_k7KJk0/ansible_module_openshift_facts.py\", line 1574, in **init**\r\n    self.system_facts = ansible_facts(module)\r\nTypeError: ansible_facts() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)\r\n", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE", "rc": 0}
2018-12-11 21:06:57,445 p=8325 u=root |         to retry, use: --limit @/usr/share/ansible/openshift-ansible/playbooks/byo/openshift_facts.retry

2018-12-11 21:06:57,445 p=8325 u=root |  PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
2018-12-11 21:06:57,445 p=8325 u=root |  g_all_hosts                : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
2018-12-11 21:06:57,446 p=8325 u=root |  localhost                  : ok=8    changed=7    unreachable=0    failed=0
2018-12-11 21:06:57,446 p=8325 u=root |  master.mine.kt.com         : ok=6    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1
2018-12-11 21:06:57,446 p=8325 u=root |  slave.mine.kt.com          : ok=6    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1

my master node : master.mine.kt.com,
my slave node : slave.mine.kt.com

Could you please help me to figure out this problem.
Note : I'm using 30 trial subscription of RHEL Openshift Enterprise.

Comment: Do you really mean OpenShift Enterprise 3.1. The latest is OpenShift Container Platform 3.11.

Comment: You are right. I'm trying with Openshift Enterprise 3.1 version. I know the latest version is 3.11.

Comment: Here is my plan of action.....1) Install Openshift Enterprise 3.1 2) Upgrade to Openshift Enterprise 3.11 to see what kind of prerequisites that I need to take it up during upgrade process.... Once again thanks for your quick reply.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? To go from 3.1 to 3.11 you would likely need to upgrade one version at a time, because jumping versions isn't readily supported. So you can't go from 3.1 to 3.11. This is assuming you can even still get 3.1 installed anymore.

Comment: Thanks Graham for your quick answer. Sorry I was bit schedule with my holiday season backup for my team. Based on your suggestion I started working on with 3.10 right now. Will keep you update if I come across any problem from upgrading 3.10 to 3.11 version. Thanks again.

Comment: Hi Team, I tried to install Openshift 3.11 Enterprise version in RHEL 7.6. prerequisites.yml is success. When I try to start with deploy_cluster.yml                             
$ ansible-playbook -i <inventory_file> playbooks/deploy_cluster.yml                          ansible-playbook execution failed with error stating "wait for control plane pods to appear"                                                                                                      Trying to login to oc login -u sysadmin:admin it says "unable to connect to the server: net/http: TLS handshake timeout"